# Using latitude, longitude of person in an application to generate Blackberry maps

Tags: blackberry, java-me

1) I have user's latitude and longitude available with me who is in New York, USA.

2) I have an address of a shop in New York, USA

Now how can I generate a route map from my location to that shop's location?

How can I fetch shop's latitude, longitude?

3) I am working on Bold-9000 simulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this KnowledgeBase article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800703/How_To_-_Invoke_BlackBerry_Maps.html?nodeid=1366963&vernum=0) for details on how to launch the BlackBerry Maps application from your own, passing it various types of data (including GPS coordinates for mapping directions).

To get the lat/long for an address there is no RIM API available, however you could use a webservice such as the one provided by Google: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html

Comment: Marc i visited that site earlier also but i couldn't find how to get the latitude , longitude of a shop corresponding to its address....

Comment: Edited my answer to include a link to a Google webservice to convert an address to lat/long coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Will this help?
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8106/Start_a_BB_device_app_from_BB_Maps_467982_11.jsp

Comment: It sounds like they want to go the other way, that is from their app they's like to open the BlackBerry Maps app with the specified coordinates mapping a route.

Comment: User Friendly this link is very good but Marc is right i have to open BB maps  and get route when specific coordinates are passed..